# How do I add URL to code below? I have mysql_fetch_array creating a row wrapped with td

Tags: php, html, arrays

Here's the row that outputs the data in td format:

```
echo "<td style='border: 1px solid black; text-align:left; padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px; width:100px; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; text-align: center'>" . $row['redtagnum'] . "</td>";
```

var myurl = "update_ncr.php"
How do create link for redtagnum to become URL pointing to myurl variable?
Everything I find is not wrapped with the td.

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to create a link to  `$myurl` wrapped in the `<td>` tags with the text `$row["redtagnum"]`

You need to put an `<a>` tag inside of the `<td>` tag

```
echo "<td style='...'>";
echo "<a href='".$myurl."'>";
echo $row["redtagnum"];
echo "</a>";
echo "</td>";
```

Comment: Okay, let me go back and check. I stripped out the long row of code like you did above, but maybe got they syntax slightly wrong - that is how I attempted to do it though. Get back to you soon as I try it.Thank you.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Now how do I send that piece of actual data (redtagnum) to the next page to run a query with that information? It is unique....06062020-1 is an example.

Comment: I know I need to create the url like update_ncr.php? .....   but not sure of how to put in the $row['redtagnum'] in the url ... And I know I need to use GET on the next page to pull that  data. In ASP it's a querystring. Is it called the same in PHP?

Comment: Okay, I got the querystring correctly as well. Just played with it a bit. Here is the code I used to push the data to the next page:  $myurl = ("update_open_ncr2.php?" . $row['redtagnum']);